# Submitted form fails to create new record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a button (that's actually a form) which creates a new record in the Quantity model of my Rails app. I have this in my view:

```
<%= form_for :quantity, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :number, value: 10 %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

However, whenever I click on the "Add" button, the app fails to create a new record. I'm not sure what's wrong. Here are the logs:

```
Processing by HomeController#search as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "quantity"=>{"number"=>"10", "user_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Add"}
  Quantity Search (4.0ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/quantities_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"_all":{"query":"","operator":"and","boost":10,"analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"","operator":"and","boost":10,"analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"","operator":"and","boost":1,"fuzziness":1,"max_expansions":3,"analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"_all":{"query":"","operator":"and","boost":1,"fuzziness":1,"max_expansions":3,"analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}}]}},"size":20,"from":0,"fields":[]}'
  Rendered home/search.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 22.5ms | Searchkick: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Here's what I have as my routes:

```
get 'search' => 'home#search'
post 'search' => 'home#search'
```

Problem appears to be that there are multiple forms in one view.

Comment: Do you have a quantities controller?  An entry in the routes file?

Comment: use `pry` and `pry-nav` gems to debug in development mode. add these gems in development group in Gemfile. Then in your controller where you want to debug add `binding.pry`. It will halt the execution of your program at that line and give you a line by line code execution option. This is how you debug such issues.

Comment: I've added logs and details about routes. Yes I do have a quantities controller but this form is found in a view linked to another controller.

Comment: You have two routes going to the same controller#action. If you are new to Rails, avoid this.